# Removal of OAuth 2.0 package

Tags: managed-package, integration, oauth2

I have released managed package for my OAuth 2.0 connected app.
My partners that are working on SF have installed the package and we are working fine.

What I am wondering about. In case that this package is removed what will happened ?
Because our partners have already installed package with all OAuth 2.0 details I guess that nothing ? Or with removal of package also will be affected current installations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the connected app settings are not physically deleted (e.g. the connected app is still in your developer organization), then those installations wouldn't be affected. There's no need for a connected app to be installed in the remote organization to be effective.